# Flutter Bad State: Too Many Elements

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

it keeps showing Bad State: Too Many Elements when i run the code for Updating Profile Page using Firebase Firestore, i have search it up online and many of the post says that its because of duplicate keys, however my code doesnt have that, can anyone help? I have 2 code files, one is the main page which is UpdateProfilePage.dart and the other is ProfileController.dart where i retrieve the values from Firebase Firestore

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttergdsc/pages/landing_page.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../controllers/profile_controller.dart';
import '../controllers/user_model.dart';

class UpdateProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
const UpdateProfilePage({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final controller = Get.put(ProfileController());

return Scaffold(
    .........
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: controller.getUserData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              UserModel userData = snapshot.data as UserModel;

              //Controllers
              final email = TextEditingController(text: userData.email);
              final password = TextEditingController(text: userData.password);
              final userName = TextEditingController(text: userData.userName);
              final phoneNo = TextEditingController(text: userData.phoneNo);

              return Column(
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      .........
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  Form(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                            controller: userName,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              label: Text("Username"),
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                            )),
                        ..................
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                                final userData = UserModel (
                                  userName: userName.text.trim(),
                                  email: email.text.trim(),
                                  password: password.text.trim(),
                                  phoneNo: phoneNo.text.trim(),
                                );
                                await controller.updateRecord(userData);
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                              side: BorderSide.none,
                              shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                            ),
                            child: Text("Update Profile",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
            } else {
              return const Center(child: Text('Something went wrong'));
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

ProfileController.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttergdsc/controllers/user_model.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'authentication_repo.dart';
import 'user_repository.dart';

class ProfileController extends GetxController {
  static ProfileController get instance => Get.find();
  final _authRepo = Get.put(AuthenticationRepository());
  final _userRepo = Get.put(UserRepository());

  final email = TextEditingController();
  final password = TextEditingController();
  final userName = TextEditingController();
  final phoneNo = TextEditingController();
  late User firebaseUser;

  Future<UserModel> getUserData() async{
    final firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if(firebaseUser != null){
      final email = firebaseUser.email;
      if(email != null){
        return _userRepo.getUserDetails(email);
      }else{
        Get.snackbar("Error", "Login to continue");
        throw Exception("Login to continue");
      }
    } else {
      Get.snackbar("Error", "User not found");
      throw Exception("User not found");
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateRecord(UserModel user) async {
    try {
      final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      await firestore.collection('Users').doc(user.id).set(user.toJson(), SetOptions(merge: true));
      print('Profile updated successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error updating profile: $error');
    }
  }

}
```